# jQuery Browser Slide to message

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jQuery code...

```
success: function(result) {
    var res = result.user_id;
    if(res > 0){

        $('#danger_container_email').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
        $('#message_email').html('This email address is already existing!');
        $('#register').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#register').removeAttr('name');
        $('#message').css('color', 'red');
        $('#success_email').attr('class','form-group has-error has-feedback');
        $('#email_glyp').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');

    }
```

and here's my html code:

```
<div id = "danger_container_email" class="col-md-12">
    <center><span id = "message_email" style = "color:red;"></span></center>
</div>
```

what I want there is when the error message shows I want the browser to focus on that part. I think it is possible but I'm not really good in jQuery. [image]

Comment: you need to focus on input box or error message?

Comment: @AravindSivam I want the browser to scroll over the error message... is that possible sir?

Comment: have you tried $('#message_email').focus(); ?

Comment: @AravindSivam Do you want to browser to *scroll* to the message?

Comment: @AravindSivam yes sir but it is now scrolling down / focusing on the error message.

Comment: @AravindSivam yes sir that is what I want.. is it possible sir?

Comment: try this $(window).scrollTop

Comment: @AravindSivam it doesn't scroll to bottom.. it goes to top.. I change the top to bottom still doesn't scroll over to the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For focus you can try this

```
$('#message_email').focus();
```

To scroll to the div try this

```
window.scrollTo(0 , $('#message_email').position().top);
```

For detail refer this url [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp)

Comment: still doesn't scroll over to the error message sir @Aravind Sivam

Comment: yeah it is but instead of going down it goes up!

Comment: you're saying about scroll?

Comment: but when it scrolltop how it focus to error message?

Comment: here's what I do  I put this code window.scrollTo(0, 500);  but it has a fixed value.. but works fine.. it scroll on the error message..